# GREP out n rows of text between two specific strings

Tags: grep

I want to grep out >contig_18, the rows of text that follow it, and stop before >contig_19.

I do not understand how to grep the many rows of text after >contig_18 without giving the exact number of line breaks.

Ex: Note there will normally be 1000+ rows of text between contigs.

```
>contig_18
GCACAGACGGCCGACTTTAGAGAATCTGAGTTTGGAGCGCTGCCGGT
GAATCCAGATGACTTAACCGGCCACGTCTCCCTATGACCTGCATTTT
GAAAGAGATCTGCTTCAGATGCGATCTCCATTAGGATATCAACTTGG
CCGATCGCATCGTCGAGAGCGGAGACACGGCAGCCAACCTTCTTGAG
AGTCCTTTTCAGCTCGCGAAGGGCTTCAAGTACTTCCGGAGAGAACG
GGTCGACAAGTGGATCAGGCAAAGTTGCGATTTCCACGCGTGTCGAT
TCTGACTCGCTCATTTGATCCCCCGTGGCATTCTGCGCGGGTTGGAG
>contig_19
```

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use `grep`, you can do this:

```
grep -A 9999 "^>contig_18" file | grep -B 9999 "^>contig_19"
```

That says to find up to 9,999 lines following `contig_18` and, from those, find up to 9,999 lines preceding `contig_19`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `awk` in your system, you can do this:

```
awk '/^>contig_18/ {f=1} f; /^>contig_19/ {f=0}' file
```

It will get all data from line starting with `>contig_18` to and inclusive lines with `>contig_19`

---

You can also use this, but I like the first better since its more custom able:

```
awk '/^>contig_18/,/^>contig_19/' file
```

Or you can use `sed`

```
sed -n '/^>contig_18/,/^>contig_19/p' file
```